# What's wrong with my usage of closest()?

Tags: jquery, closest

I have a set of nested `DIV`'s and I need to find each outer box from the inner box. According to [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), the `closest()` method *gets the first ancestor element that matches the selector*. So I've tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css"><!--
div{
    margin: 1em;
    padding: em;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
--></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
jQuery(function($){
    $(".direccion-html").closest("div").css({borderColor: "red"});
});
//--></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <div class="direccion-html">Foo</div>
</div>
 <div>
    <div class="direccion-html">Bar</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

However, my closest() selector is fetching the element itself, not any of its ancestors. What am I doing wrong? It must be an obvious error but I can't get it...

## Update:

I've composed this from Nick's answer:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".direccion-html").each(function(){
        $(this).parents("div:first").css({borderColor: "red"});
    });
});
```

Comment: There's no need for the `.each` :) it'll work on multiple elements as is ;)

Comment: @Nick Craver, I forgot to say it in the original example but I have several boxes. If I don't use each it matches the first common parent of all boxes rather than each box's parent.

Comment: @Álvaro - Oh right, duh, you're absolutely right `:first` throws things off a bit. I added an alternative for this without the `.each()`, just traverse to the `.parent()` before you use `.closest()` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) starts with the current element, if it's matches then that's the closest.  If you want the nearest that's *not* the element, use [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) with the same selector and [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".direccion-html").parents("div:first").css({borderColor: "red"});
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/y7xrZ/).  Or, an alternatively route that works for many elements:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".direccion-html").parent().closest("div").css({borderColor: "red"});
});
```

[Test that version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/y7xrZ/2/).

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I was missing the important subtlety that it can actually match the element itself and not only its ancestors.